# Python Loop Overwriting Last HTML Write

Tags: python, selenium

This script loops at the "while True:" written to scrape data from several pages by clicking the next button at the bottom, but I cannot figure out how to structure the code to continue writing to the HTML as it paginates. Instead, it overwrites the html results written previously. Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
while True:
    time.sleep(10)

    golds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".widgetContainer #widgetContent > div.singleCell")
    print("found %d golds" % len(golds))  

    template = """\
        <tr class="border">
            <td class="image"><img src="{0}"></td>\
            <td class="title"><a href="{1}" target="_new">{2}</a></td>\
            <td class="price">{3}</td>
        </tr>"""

    lines = []

    for gold in golds:
        goldInfo = {}

        goldInfo['title'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealTitle > span').text
        goldInfo['link'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealTitle').get_attribute('href')
        goldInfo['image'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealImage img').get_attribute('src')

        try:
            goldInfo['price'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('.priceBlock > span').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            goldInfo['price'] = 'No price display'

        line = template.format(goldInfo['image'], goldInfo['link'], goldInfo['title'], goldInfo['price'])
        lines.append(line)

    try:
        #clicks next button
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next→").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

    time.sleep(10)

    html = """\
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr class='headers'>
                        <td class='image'></td>
                        <td class='title'>Product</td>
                        <td class='price'>Price / Deal</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class='data'>
                    {0}
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>\
    """

    f = open('./result.html', 'w')
    f.write(html.format('\n'.join(lines)))
f.close()
```

Comment: Try to replace `f = open('./result.html', 'w')` with `f = open('./result.html', 'a')`

Comment: Thanks Andersson, perfect. Do you want to post that as an answer to I can accept that answer?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588292/python-loop-overwriting-last-html-write/50588402#50588402) is more informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the file in append mode by

```
f = open('./result.html', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the different modes when opening a file at the very end of your script: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending

And then there's more

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file. Append 'b' to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the 'b' has no effect.

So you have a couple options available. You might use `a` since you want to append data to it.

Or you could move the file opening outside the loop so that you are not constantly re-opening the file, depending on your needs.

```
f = open('./result.html', 'w')
while True:
  # do stuff
  f.write (...)
f.close()
```